# The name of a group of order 24

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutations

I encountered a group $G =\langle(1,3,2,4),(3,5,4,6)\rangle\subseteq S_6$ in my study, but I do not know its name.

Let $f=(1,3,2,4)$ and $g=(3,5,4,6)$. We have $g^2=fg^2f$, and thus $\langle f,g^2\rangle\simeq D_4$. I have proved that $\langle f,g\rangle=\langle f,g^2\rangle \cup \:g\langle f,g^2\rangle \cup\:fg \langle f,g^2 \rangle$, so $G$ is of order 24.

I think this specific group must have a name. Thanks a lot if you tell me its name.

Comment: Where did this problem arise? (This looks rather like an exercise)

Comment: @YemonChoi I was calculating the group of all linear fractional transformations that fix n distinct points on the extended complex plane. When n=6 and the the six points are 0, \infty, 1, i, -1, -i, the result is the group above.

Comment: According to GAP, this is $S_4$.

Comment: The description in the comment gives the orientation-preserving symmetries of the octahedron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an easy exercise to show that $G$ is isomorphic to $S_4$ in its action on $6=\binom{4}{2}$ pairs of the four points of its natural action.